# pug template engine in service worker

Tags: javascript, pug, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have compiled a pug template **temp1.js** using the below command.

**pug --client --no-debug temp1.pug**

The compiled file contains a function named **template**.I want to know how to use this file in my service worker. Means how to call this function. And is there any way to change the function name.

**temp1.js**

```
function template(locals) {var pug_html = "", pug_mixins = {}, pug_interp;pug_html = pug_html + "\u003C!DOCTYPE html\u003E\u003Chtml\u003E\u003Chead\u003E\u003Cmeta charset=\"utf-8\"\u003E\u003Cmeta http-equiv=\"content-language\" content=\"en\"\u003E\u003Cmeta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no\"\u003E\u003Cmeta name=\"format-detection\" content=\"telephone=no\"\u003E\u003C\u002Fhead\u003E\u003Cbody\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"mfw pDDetail\" id=\"buyPage\" data-role=\"page\"\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"mfw\"\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"imgGal wd100 lf tc\"\u003E\u003Cdiv id=\"mobilePdGal\"\u003E\u003Cul active=\"0\" style=\"transform: translateX(0px)\"\u003E\u003Cli style=\"display:inline-block;position:relative\"\u003E\u003C\u002Fli\u003E\u003C\u002Ful\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"firstFold dp\" id=\"pHeaderId\"\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\"price-n-project\"\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E\u003C\u002Fbody\u003E\u003C\u002Fhtml\u003E";;return pug_html;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `template` function include `temp1.js` in your page, then call `template()`, which will render an HTML string that you can append to the DOM:

```html
<script src="temp1.js"></script>
<script>

  var model = { templateName: 'Template 1' };
  var html = template(model);
  $('body').append(html);

</script>
```

The `temp1.pug` template file I used to generate `temp1.js` has a data model with a single variable, `templateName`. The data model for your `temp1.pug` template file may have multiple variables or none at all.

```js
// temp1.pug
p This is #{templateName}
```

**Template Function Name**

If you want to change the template function name as you generate `temp1.js` use the `--name` option:

`pug --client --no-debug temp1.pug --name "myTemplate"`

Then you would call `myTemplate({/* ... */})` to render the HTML in your page.

Example: [Pug Template Function](https://jsfiddle.net/stephentillman/7Ln3vL03/)